# Create a hyperlink to another sheet within the same workbook to first non-blank cell

Tags: excel, vba, button, hyperlink

I have a main sheet in which I manage my trades for currency on the FOREX.  On that main sheet I have made buttons that I would like to hyperlink to the subsequent sheets that hold the daily data for each specific currency pair.

I am able to create a hyperlink to the sheet itself by using the hyperlink function but I want the hyperlink to actually find the first blank cell in column B and then count up 10 cells so that the last ten cells are visible on the sheet.

I have tried using Indirect, Offset, CountA, and Match combinations and variations to no avail.  Please help.[Main Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLp6z.png)
[Daily Sheet Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFsKb.png)

Comment: Please show us the code your buttons invoke.  In the simplest terms, I think you're looking for myrow = sh.cells(sh.rows.count, column_to_look_at).end(xlup).row -10

Comment: Right now I have not used VBA.  I have only used the hyperlink function and the wizard to try and connect them.  So you recommend using an ActiveX Button and using VBA to invoke the command on Click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simplify, you can replicate this code for each button.  Change only one line for each button (and the subroutine name, of course)

```
Sub JPY_Daily_click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JPY_Daily")
myrow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 10
sh.Activate
sh.Range("A" & myrow).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code but it fails to compile at strSubAddress = "'" & shName & "'!A" & myLoc.  It says that "'!A" is not valid.  I tried using column C and all to no avail.

Comment: I got that work but then I received an error at the TextToDisplay:=ActiveCell.Value.

Comment: I have added your suggested code and it returns a compile error "Type Mismatch" and highlights on the line 'myrow=getbottom("JPY_Daily") -10' and highlights in blue the JPY_Daily.  The sheet name is actually JPY Dly and I changed it as such....Also I tried with using the sheet number instead of the name and it gave me the same error again.  And yes you are totally correct about my goal and that I have to create one of these for each button.

Comment: where do I add that syntax to call it that way???  Sorry for so many questions... I truly appreciate your help.

Comment: K, new code above.  I eliminated the function and just did everything in the sub.  it's not that much code to replicate anyway, and it makes it simpler.  Just make a copy of this code for each button, and change the ("JPY_Daily") to the sheet you want.

Comment: Hrothgar you are amazing!!!  Thank you so much for the help.  It works like a charm.  And it has given me such insight into some basics of VBA.  Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Glad to help.  Also glad that the process has given you some insights.  VBA is not all that complicated.  It's just 43,200 simple things :)